# Array rendering is reversed when editing post

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have the following Livewire code, it lists all the chirps (posts) I have; the problem is that when I click to edit one of the chirps, the whole `$chirps` array seems to render upside down. I added the id of each chirp for clarity:

The actual editing process works just fine.
[image: normal rendering]
[image: When editing]

```php
<?php

use Livewire\Volt\Component;
use App\Models\Chirp;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Livewire\Attributes\On;

new class extends Component {
    public Collection $chirps;

    public ?Chirp $editing = null;

    public function mount(): void
    {
        $this->getChirps();
    }

    #[On('chirp-created')]
    #[On('chirp-updated')]
    public function getChirps(): void
    {
        $this->editing = null;
        $this->chirps = Chirp::with('user')
            ->latest()
            ->get();
    }

    #[On('chirp-edit-cancelled')]
    public function resetEdittingChirp()
    {
        $this->editing = null;
    }

    public function edit(Chirp $chirp): void
    {
        $this->editing = $chirp;
    }
}; ?>

<div class="mt-6 bg-white shadow-sm rounded-lg divide-y">
    @foreach ($chirps as $chirp)
        {{ $chirp->id }}
        <div class="p-6 flex space-x-2">

            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6 text-gray-600 -scale-x-100" fill="none"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">

                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                    d="M8 12h.01M12 12h.01M16 12h.01M21 12c0 4.418-4.03 8-9 8a9.863 9.863 0 01-4.255-.949L3 20l1.395-3.72C3.512 15.042 3 13.574 3 12c0-4.418 4.03-8 9-8s9 3.582 9 8z" />

            </svg>

            <div class="flex-1">

                <div class="flex justify-between items-center">

                    <div>

                        <span class="text-gray-800">{{ $chirp->user->name }}</span>

                        <small
                            class="ml-2 text-sm text-gray-600">{{ $chirp->created_at->format('j M Y, g:i a') }}</small>
                        @unless ($chirp->created_at->eq($chirp->updated_at))
                            <small class="text-sm text-gray-600"> &middot; {{ __('edited on') }}
                                {{ $chirp->updated_at->format('j M Y, g:i a') }}`</small>
                        @endunless

                    </div>
                    @if ($chirp->user->is(auth()->user()))
                        <x-dropdown>

                            <x-slot name="trigger">

                                <button>

                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-4 w-4 text-gray-400"
                                        viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">

                                        <path
                                            d="M6 10a2 2 0 11-4 0 2 2 0 014 0zM12 10a2 2 0 11-4 0 2 2 0 014 0zM16 12a2 2 0 100-4 2 2 0 000 4z" />

                                    </svg>

                                </button>

                            </x-slot>

                            <x-slot name="content">

                                <x-dropdown-link wire:click="edit({{ $chirp }})">

                                    {{ __('Edit') }}

                                </x-dropdown-link>

                            </x-slot>

                        </x-dropdown>
                    @endif
                </div>

                @if ($chirp->is($editing))
                    <livewire:chirps.edit :chirp="$chirp" />
                @else
                    <p class="mt-4 text-lg text-gray-900">{{ $chirp->message }}</p>
                @endif

            </div>

        </div>
    @endforeach

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of...

```
@foreach ($chirps as $chirp)
```

Use:

```
@foreach ($chirps->sortByDesc('created_at') as $chirp)
```

Also, Livewire provides the `wire:key` directive, which can be used to explicitly set a unique key for each element in a loop.

```
<div wire:key="{{ $chirp->id }}" class="p-6 flex space-x-2">
```

Comment: That did fix it, but isn't `$this->chirps = Chirp::with('user')->latest()` supposed to take care of that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 @foreach ($chirps->sortDesc('created_at') as $chirp)
```

it will sort the chirps in descending order.

By sorting the chirps before rendering, you should maintain the desired order when you edit a chirp.

Comment: How is your answer any different from @karl-hill 's answer? Please, avoid adding duplicate answers. 

Comment: It's wrong, that's how it's different.  The correct answer is:  @foreach ($chirps->sortByDesc('created_at') as $chirp).  sortByDesc. not sortDesc.   I also have no idea why this isn't in the actual tutorial.   I've downvoted this and upvoted the correct original answer.